# cannot add view to nested linear layout in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I want to build whole fragment layout programatically and dynamically. So I've created this code:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_container, container, false);

    final FrameLayout rootView = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.empty_container);

    final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    rootView.addView(linearLayout);

    final Button button = new Button(getActivity());
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    button.setText("button name");
    button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));

    linearLayout.addView(button);

    return view;
}
```

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/empty_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I cant figure out why this is not working properly. Button is not visible at all (but linear layout is visible - whole screen is black). When I set one of button Layout params to `MATCH_PARENT` it suddenly appears, but when I set it to 100 px or `WRAP_CONTENT` its not showing.

Comment: Open Android Device Monitor, run the app, then check your DOM with the tree viewer. You will be able to see if Views are being added to your DOM.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html

Comment: using hierarchy viewer I found button was hidden under the toolbar, thanks @RussellElfenbein

Comment: no probs, mate. I'll add it as a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are adding it.
Open Android Device Monitor, run the app, then check your DOM with the tree viewer. You will be able to see if Views are being added to your DOM.

developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make the root view a `LinearLayout`? Then you can just cast the root view to a `LinearLayout`, you don't need to find it by id because you already have reference to it. Also not sure what you intend by this line `linearLayout.setGravity(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);` Check this link for valid values to put into `setGravity` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html

Comment: sorry it was supposed to be `setOrientation` not gravity, and what if I needed to have multiple linear layouts inside `FrameLayout` with even more children? I have a workaround for my problem, I'm just wondering, why this code is not working, and why changing one of buttons params to `MATCH_PARENT` makes button appear. EDIT: found the solution posted above...

Answer (score 0):

The button was hiding under the toolbar, and size 100px x 100px was not enough to display it. Hierarchy viewer helped me figure this out it.